# For $E\in \Bbb{R}^3$,$(x,y,z)\in E \iff (x,y,-z)\in E$, and linear $ f:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}$, if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the center of mass, $z_0=0$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $E\subset \Bbb{R}^3$ be a measurable set (i.e. $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}1_{E}$ exists) and let $v(E)\ne 0$. Let $f$ be a linear function $f:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}$, and let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the center of mass of $f$, i.e. $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)={1\over v(E)}\int_{E}f$ which is the average value of $f$. Prove that if $(x,y,z)\in E \iff (x,y,-z)\in E$, then $z_0=0$.

I can't seem to arrive at something trying to solve it. I tried setting $f(x,y,z)=b+a_1x+a_2y+a_3z$. I just can't tell how to derive $z_0$ from ${1\over v(E)}\int_{E}f$. Trying to substitute $f$ by its general linear representation (above), I just get very long expressions not seeming to indicate anything about $z_0$.

I therefore didn't include the redundant, sloppy, multifaceted calculation of the integral, and I **will** include it if you believe it is necessary for things to get ahead. I there any approach any of you could provide?

Comment: I wonder if there's a slick way to phrase this in terms of a $\Bbb{Z}/2$ group action and maybe easily generalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your center of the mass formula is wrong. Let's call $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$, then the center of mass $\vec{r_0}=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by:
$$\vec{r_0}=\frac{1}{v(E)}\int_E f(\vec{r})\vec{r} d\vec{r}$$
Now we can write 
$$z_0=\frac{1}{v(E)}\int_E f(\vec{r})\ dx\ dy\ z\ dz$$
When you integrate at some particular $(x,y)$, you can change variable from $z$ to $-z$, since both points are in $E$. The integral is then 0.
$$\int_E f(\vec{r})\ dx\ dy\ z\ dz=\int_{xrange}dx\int_{yrange}dy\int_{-Z(x,y)}^{Z(x,y)}f(x,y,z)z\ dz\\
=-\int_{xrange}dx\int_{yrange}dy\int_{Z(x,y)}^{-Z(x,y)}f(x,y,z)z\ dz\\
=-\int_{xrange}dx\int_{yrange}dy\int_{-Z(x,y)}^{Z(x,y)}f(x,y,-z)(-z)\ d(-z)\\
=-\int_E f(\vec{r})\ dx\ dy\ z\ dz$$

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on it. The formula represented above was written that way **within** the question. Are you suggesting it was wrong?